# Is there a port of prefuse in javascript/flash?

Tags: javascript, flash, graphics

http://prefuse.org/

It's originally written in `java`,but I want to do it with client script,like `javascript`/`flash`.

Answer (score 2):

The following are essentially from the same author as Prefuse:

JavaScript

- [D3](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/)
- [Protovis](http://mbostock.github.com/protovis/)

Flash

- [Flare](http://flare.prefuse.org/)